# Hibernate check deletion constraints

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, constraints

I am using Spring - Hibernate to control models in my application. The models are linked to each other (one-to-many, many-to-many, almost kinds of relationships), and now I have a problem when deleting one entity which is being used by other entities. The problem is I want to show the detail message that informs exactly what other objects (type, name) are using the entity that I am going to delete. It's not the common message about Constraint violation that Hibernate throws me.
For example: `Car --> Person, House --> Person`; then when I delete one Person who has a car and house, the message will show "There are Car (named Ford Mustang) and House (named MyHouse) linked to this Person".
1. So is there any method from Hibernate support this requirement? I guess there's no implementation for this specific requirement.
2. If not any utility available for this problem, I am thinking about below solutions:
- in each entity class (i.e Person), I will define all checking method that detect linking from the this entity to other entities, for example:

```
class Person {
     // Properties
     // Checking methods, return type and name of linked objects
     public Map<String, String> getLinkedCars() {
         // Query to DB to get linked cars
         // return a Map contain Class name along with object name <Car, Ford Mustang>
     }

     public Map<String, String> getLinkedHouses() {
         // Query to DB to get linked houses
         // return a Map contain Class name along with object name <House, MyHouse>
     }
}
```

-and then, in service before deleting Person entity, I will use reflection mechanism to collect results from checking methods (whose name is started with "getLinkedXXX"), and build the detail error messages.
So is this solution good? About the performance, and the convention of MVC (because I have to query data inside model class)?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE

Comment: @MasudCSECUET Won't that just delete it without giving any info for an error message?

Comment: Make the associations bidirectional, and you'll have the set of cars and houses linked to the car directly in the Person entity. That said, I don't think this is a reasonable thing to do in every situation. If you delete a Person who has made 3000 phone calls and who has 500 friends, you don't want to list all these entities.

Comment: Don't do database calls in your model object. Use a dao/helper in your action.

Comment: @JBNizet: I just show some of top entities in the error messages not the whole things.
So is there any way to detect all foreign constraints from outside link to this entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (not so simple) approach is to scan your entity class for `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` annotated fields and perform checking so neat error message can be provided to user. Following sample code assumes you only annotate the field, not the getters method, eg:

```
public class Person {
  @OneToMany(..)
  private List<House> houses;
  //...
}
```

First get the list of all fields using reflection:

```
Fields[] fields = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Then iterate and check for `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` annotations

```
for(Field f : fields) {
   if( f.getAnnotation(OneToMany.class) != null || 
       f.getAnnotation(ManyToMany.class) != null) {
     // Here you know f has to be checked before the person is deleted ...
   }
}
```

The value of a field of a particular person object can be obtained using:

```
Person p = // fetch a person ..
Field f = // assume f is the "List<House> houses" field
List<House> houses = (List<House>) f.get(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I had to check if an entity could be safely deleted to avoid foreign key constraint violations. This is how I solved:

First, I created an annotation to mark the entity that needs to be checked before deletion:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = SafeDeleteValidator.class)
public @interface SafeDelete {
  String message() default "{lima.jefferson.SafeDelete.message}";
  Class<?>[] groups() default { };
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Then I created another annotation to be applied to any method that will be used to check if the entity can be deleted:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface CheckForDelete {
}
```

In the entity class I used these annotations like this:

```
@SafeDelete(message = "Couldn't delete this entity due to...")
public class MyEntity {

    @CheckForDelete
    public Boolean checkForDelete() {
        // Insert your business logic here
        return true;
    }

}
```

And finally, the validator for the `SafeDelete` annotation:

```
public class SafeDeleteValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SafeDelete, Object> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(SafeDelete constraintAnnotation) {

  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Object object, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    Method[] methods = object.getClass().getMethods();

    return Arrays.stream(methods)
          .filter(m -> m.getAnnotation(CheckForDelete.class) != null)
          // Deal with the exception here 
          .map(m -> (Boolean) m.invoke(object))
          .reduce(true, (a, b) -> a && b);
  }

}
```

Then you can follow the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802765/spring-boot-rest-constraint-for-delete) to apply the validation to deletion only.